# Is there a safe way to make a HashSet<int[]> without manually wrapping it in another object?

Tags: java

I have recently been having problems with Java apparently swallowing entire `int[]` which are different from each other in value when I try to merge two `HashSet<int[]>` using the `addAll` method. I do not have a small working example because I only observe this behavior in a large dataset of a million.

My understanding is that the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `int[]` are not implemented to respect either the content or the pointer value of the reference to an `int` array. 
Is there a way to modify the `HashSet` or the `int[]` short of wrapping it, to make it safe to work with `HashSet<int[]>`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the equals and hashCode methods of the int[] are not implemented to respect either the content or the pointer value of the reference to an int array.?" I'm not following.

Comment: There should not be any problems. Any two different array instances will be deemed unequal from the `HashSet`'s perpsective and that's it.

Comment: What is not "safe" with what you are doing currently? Perhaps a snippet of your code and an example of "unsafe" behavior would help to explain the problem you are having.

Comment: I think he needs an equal check for a1 [1,2,3] and a2[1,2,3]? You should override the hashCode and the equals method.

Comment: @TomG, there are two possible ways to implement equals and hashCode. One is to make them return the same if the array REFERENCE (that is, the value of the pointer) is equal. Another way is to make them return the same if the array CONTENT (that is, the values inside the array) are the same.

Comment: @Joni, what's not safe is that two different arrays are being treated as the same by the HashSet and it is killing one of them. I will try to create a smaller scale example of this, but so far I've only seen it in large data sets.

Comment: What do you mean - did you merged two `int[]` into one `HashSet` which are different in (i) reference and (ii) in content and one of them is purged?

Comment: If you find that happening you have found a bug in the JVM. Are you by any chance accessing the HashSet from different threads without appropriate synchronization?

Comment: @merlin2011 I understand the `equals` contract. I don't believe that arrays violate that contract. As Joni says, if so, you've found a JVM bug. As far as I know, all arrays use reference equality to fulfill `equals()`.

Comment: As far as I know is `[].equals` equality by reference and `Arrays.equals(...)` equality by value.

Comment: I will dig into this and see if I can find the specific instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next program:

```
final int[] a1 = { 1 };
final int[] a2 = { 1 };
final int[] a3 = a1;

System.out.println("a1.equals(a2): " + a1.equals(a2));
System.out.println("a1.equals(a3): " + a1.equals(a3));
```

outputs:

```
a1.equals(a2): false
a1.equals(a3): true
```

In regards to your message:

> My understanding is that the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the int[]
>   are not implemented to respect either the content or the pointer value
>   of the reference to an int array.

It means that the `equals` and `hashCode` do respect the pointer value, but not the value.

I see two potential reasons why Java has swallowed one of your `int[]`.

1. If your are filling the `HashSet` from several threads. `HashSet` is not synchronized. You need to create it as next: `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<int[]>())`. As you having so millions objects, the chance that collision on add happens is very high.
2. Array is a modifiable object. You might have a bug in your program if it is using old array instances on reading.

Comment: I think #2 is probably what it was.